# Getting URL from $_GET with all parameters

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

Welcome,

Simple code:

```
<?
$parametrs = (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '');
echo $parametrs;
?>
```

In URL's parameter i've:

```
https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12688238_10153608378188197_489584030822190108_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_eui2=AeF838NYAK8LUEwdXcefThvdaa0MIWy1XfuIQkSmJMh-zlpCFVHFpQyYJVBUXK79YiASxQE6cyIgTIaGXnSCoWO0YuXTpj9g6N4RoYlJnE5wOw&oh=e0a1aef0f5834746c73991e937fdae23&oe=5C26DFD6
```

But script shows me only:

```
https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12688238_10153608378188197_489584030822190108_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100
```

How can I grab all string from $_GET['url']?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You dont have $_GET['url']... you have  $_GET['n_cat'] and  $_GET['oa']

Comment: I've just noticed it now... Thanks! :-)

Comment: sure... is there still any question ? are you looking for the url displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the parameters as array just in one call, like this way:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe u have a better vision for this code?
`function getFullURL() {
 $parameters = $_REQUEST;
 $full_url = '';

 if (strpos($parameters, 'img_url') !== false) {
  $full_url .= $parameters['img_url'];
 }
 if (strpos($parameters, '_nc_eui2') !== false) {
  $full_url .= '&_nc_eui2=' . $parameters['_nc_eui2'];
 }
 if (strpos($parameters, 'oh') !== false) {
  $full_url .= '&oh=' . $parameters['oh'];
 }
 if (strpos($parameters, 'oe') !== false) {
  $full_url .= '&oe=' . $parameters['oe'];
 }

 return $full_url;
}`

Comment: To get full url use this - 
`function getFullURL() { 
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}`

To get each params to filter it and build the url again use the `$_REQUEST` variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't URL-encode the parameter to the original script. So the `&` in the `url=` parameter is being treated as the end of that parameter, not part of the parameter. The original URL should be like this:

```
?url=https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12688238_10153608378188197_489584030822190108_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100%26_nc_eui2=AeF838NYAK8LUEwdXcefThvdaa0MIWy1XfuIQkSmJMh-zlpCFVHFpQyYJVBUXK79YiASxQE6cyIgTIaGXnSCoWO0YuXTpj9g6N4RoYlJnE5wOw%26oh=e0a1aef0f5834746c73991e937fdae23%26oe=5C26DFD6
```

All the `&` in the URL have been replaced with `%26`.

If you're creating the URL in PHP you can use `urlencode($url)` to do this. If you're creating it in JavaScript use `encodeURIComponent(url)`. If you're using jQuery AJAX, put all the parameters to functions like `$.get` or `$.ajax` in an object, and jQuery will automatically encode everything correctly.